# How to code a binary search algorithm that breaks the instances into 1/3 and 2/3

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

I am trying to design a ***recursive*** binary-search algorithm (in pseudocode) to find an arbitrary number k in a (sorted) list of n integers, which breaks the instance into two parts: one with 1/3 of
the elements and another one with 2/3. I then need to compare its complexity with a more traditional binary search algorithm, which breaks the instances into halves.

So far, here is what I have come up with in terms of the pseudocode - I am not certain if it is correct. However, I am not too sure as to how I can go about comparing their time complexity.

```
  BinarySearch(A, value, low, high) {
      // invariants: value > A[i] for all i < low
                     value < A[i] for all i > high
      if (high < low)
          return not_found // value would be inserted at index "low"
      third = (low + high) / 3
      if (A[third] > value)
          return BinarySearch(A, value, low, third-1)
      else if (A[third] < value)
          return BinarySearch(A, value, third+1, high)
      else
          return third
  }
```

Comment: might be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `third = (low + high) / 3` is plain wrong. If, for example, `low == 100` and `high == 110`, you'd end up with `third == 70`. Not exactly what you are after.

The correct breakup is `third = low + (high - low)/3`.

Regarding complexity, think of the worst case, in which the target number a max one (that is always in the larger partition). How does the search space shrinks paer recursion level?